# Mock a java web service Rest who invoke a static extern methode

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, mocking, powermock

I want to make an unit test of a web service (Rest- jersey) this is how my web service look likes

```
public class WebService {

        public string webServiceMethode {
               ...
               String a =   ExternalClass.staticMethode("aa");
               ..
              return b

           }
    }
```

as you can see the web service methode invoke a static methode in a external class, in test class my idea is to call the web service by Rest-Assured and mock the statics methode by Powermock and here my test methode logic

```
public class WebServicetest {
      @Test
      public void testWebServiceMethode {
               mockStatic(ExternalClass.class);
               when(ExternalClass.staticMethode(Mockito.any()))
                                   .thenReturn("ok");
              given().accept(CotentType.JSON)
              .body(MyObject).when().post(new URI("/test"));
    }
  }
```

the given() methode will call the web service and the when().theReturn() will replace the return of the external static methode so the call works good but not the mock.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

A) Understand that **static** is an abnormality within good OOP. It kills polymorphism, and it leads to *super tight* coupling between your classes. The *sane* thing to do: avoid using *static* this way.

*static* can be OK, but as soon as it hampers your ability to do (easy) unit-testing, you are doing something **wrong**.

So, my first answer is: get rid of that *static* method.

B) In case you want to continue doing the wrong thing (using PowerMock) - simply read the [tutorials](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/powermockito/powermock-mock-static-method-example/) or the [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockstatic). There are various requirements in order make static mocking work. You need to use the @Runner(PowerMockRunner), and you need to use the @PrepareForTest annotation (for the class on which you want to mock static classes). So that PowerMock can go in and manipulate the byte code of your production code so it can do its magic.